# Why is the Wronskian of these two functions equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-function

I can't seem to get the right answer

$
f = e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$ and $g =e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}erf(y)$ where $erf(y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-\alpha^2}d\alpha$

I get $W = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} - ye^{y^2}erf(y)$

Am I making some kind of stupid mistake that I can't get the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get
$$
W(f,g)(y)=f(y)g'(y)-g(y)f'(y)=
e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}
   \left(e^{\frac{y^2}{2}} y
   \text{ erf}(y)+\frac{2
   e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}\right)-e^{y^2} y
   \text{ erf}(y)
={2\over \sqrt{\pi}}.
$$

Comment: yup, very stupid mistake! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer(s), you should "upvote" any and all that are helpful by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer. If one answer strikes you as "best" you can "accept" that answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: It's not letting me do it. First it said I can do it in 6 minutes, now says in 1 minute. Will do in a minute! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, I don't mean to harass you about it. Just trying to help educate those who may be new. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have calculated $g'$ incorrectly. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$$g'(y) = yg(y) + e^{y^2/2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y^2} = yg(y) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y^2/2} $$

Try recalculating now the Wronksian.

Comment: yea, I did it wrong! Thanks!